# Passing array to another class - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I manage to pass the following array from MessagesTableViewController.m to arraySelectedCategory in another class called MessageDetailViewController.m:

```
self.messageDetailViewController.arraySelectedCategory =
        [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Value 1",@"Value 2", @"Value 3", nil];
```

but how do I hand over an array stored in: `NSMutableArray *categories;`

```
self.messageDetailViewController.arraySelectedCategory = ?????
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I take it that you want a copy of the `categories` array?

```
self.messageDetailViewController.arraySelectedCategory = [categories copy];
```

Comment: @Darko Yes. And if that's not what your're looking for, a simple `self.messageDetailViewController.arraySelectedCategory = categories` should do.

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot. I am still new to Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults. The value can be used in whole program.